# rails generate not working with mongoid

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

I just created an app in rails with mongoid.

When I attempt to follow the tutorial on the mongoid site and run

```
rails g mongoid:config
```

I get the following set of errors.

```
/Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/activesupport-3.1.1/lib/active_support/whiny_nil.rb:48:in `method_missing': undefined method `values' for nil:NilClass (NoMethodError)
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/mongoid-2.3.4/lib/mongoid/railtie.rb:64:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:96:in `initialize!'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
from /Users/XXXXXX/melodizr/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/application.rb:83:in `require_environment!'
from /Users/XXXXXX/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.1.1/lib/rails/commands.rb:22:in `<top (required)>'
from script/rails:6:in `require'
from script/rails:6:in `<main>'
```

Please help, this is killing me, I feel like I'm not missing anything but its late and I'm probably wrong.

Comment: show the piece of code where you have use method values !!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

What version of rails are you running?

Something is messed up. Make sure you have the latest gems (don't specify versions in your gemfile):

Run all of these in your rails app dir:

```
gem update --system
gem update
bundle install
bundle update
```

Now that you are up to date try it again. If it stil barfs, just make the file yourself. All that this generator does is make mongoid.yml in the config directory that looks like this:

```
development:
  host: localhost
  database: mongoid_test_development

test:
  host: localhost
  database: mongoid_test_test

# set these environment variables on your prod server
production:
  host: <%= ENV['MONGOID_HOST'] %>
  port: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PORT'] %>
  username: <%= ENV['MONGOID_USERNAME'] %>
  password: <%= ENV['MONGOID_PASSWORD'] %>
  database: <%= ENV['MONGOID_DATABASE'] %>
  # slaves:
  #   - host: slave1.local
  #     port: 27018
  #   - host: slave2.local
  #     port: 27019
```

Comment: While this should fix the problem, his specific  issue is the mongoid.yml problem I outlined.

Answer (score 3):

This exact issue is caused when mongoid.yml is missing the environment section.  The docs say do this:

```
host: localhost   
database: my_database
```

But they assume you've used the generator which REALLY does something like this:

```
development:
    host: localhost
    database: my_database
```

That line in the railtie is parsing the yml file assuming you've got an environment set up.  Note the other answer that alludes to this and if you followed the instructions WOULD fix it assuming you force overrode the existing broken mongoid.yml

Answer (score 2):

I have observed this issue when you fail to include the three RAILS_ENV sections in your mongoid.yml.  I have found that you **MUST** include all three sections in mongoid.yml YAML config file as below...

```
development:
  host: foo-bar
  .....
test:
  host: test-bar
  ....
production:
  host: prod-bar
  ....
```

Answer (score 2):

I had to remove, temporarily, the gem `spring` for it to work. Otherwise the task `rails g mongoid:config` would not finish executing.